# Getting rid of width attribute and using something else to line up both texts

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to align these texts with each other automatically?

I want to align the pink word with *group* At the top so they are both matching at the same level

[image]

```css
#title {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  font-size: 0.5vw;
  font-family: 'Armata';
  text-shadow: 0 0 80px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!-- This the table texts at the top -->

<table id="topTable" width="100%">
  <tr class="heading">
    <th width='1%'>ID</th>
    <th width='15%'>Name</th>
    <th width='5%'>Money</th>
    <th width='25%'>Job</th>
    <th width='15%'>Group</th>
    <th width='5%'>WP</th>
    <th width='5%'>Ping</th>
    <th width='1%'>Country</th>
  </tr>
</table>

<!-- This the pink table i want to align with the one at the top -->

<tr class="playersTable">
  <th width="5%">' ..playerID.. '</th>
  <th width="25%">' .. sanitize(name) .. '</th>
  <th width="15%">' .. (money) .. '</th>
  <th width="15%">' .. job .. '</th>
  <th width="15%">' .. group .. '</th>
  <th width="5%">' .. wantedLevel .. '</th>
  <th width="5%">' .. ping .. '</th>
  <th width="15%">' .. country .. '</th>
</tr>
```

I want to get rid of this width stuff and hopefully do it automatically, sorry if anything is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

i would get rid of the % widths and try to combine the tables into one. use css to set width of each column if necessary and align the columns to your liking. doing so would give you consistent horizontal text alignment on all columns and control over how you want to style each row or column accordingly.

```css
.table {
  width: 100%;
  
}

.table tr {
  text-align: left;
}

.table th {
  /* style however you like for the header row here */
  font-weight: bold;
}


/* use n-th child value select which column you'd like to style differently from default */
.table td:nth-child(5), .table th:nth-child(5) {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Money</th>
    <th>Job</th>
    <th>Group</th>
    <th>WP</th>
    <th>Ping</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>' ..playerID.. '</td>
    <td>' .. sanitize(name) .. '</td>
    <td>' .. (money) .. '</td>
    <td>' .. job .. '</td>
    <td>' .. group .. '</td>
    <td>' .. wantedLevel .. '</td>
    <td>' .. ping .. '</td>
    <td>' .. country .. '</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Is there's any way to do keep it like that but to have the <td> outside of the table?

Comment: [link](https://i.imgur.com/anU63PM.jpg)
@user3366943
This the closer i got i added 2 different tables but added the same class for each other so they match but still not perfect i really can't use them in the same exact table you know.

Comment: it's bad html structure to use <td> without the enclosing <table> tag. if you have to have two tables, you'll need to specify the width of each column and use the same table class.

see this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tpcuoemb/)

Comment: Thank you it works but let's say i wanna move name a bit to the left

how? i know how to use the nth child but i don't wanna move it with a stupid way then i effect the others

Comment: [link](https://i.imgur.com/BJGrZ32.jpg) See what i mean the name is a bit to the right

what if i wanna move it to the left a bit without messing with anything else

Comment: can you pls provide the html structure so i can take a look at what you're doing? you can add an extra class to the name column inside that table. that class may be to adjust the left padding to less than the inherited or default from table.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vydbnLf5/ Here you go mate this exactly how i use it

I just want to be able to move any of them a bit to the right or the left

also another thing if you don't mind idk if it will be even possible with this html setup

Let's the player name is long the table moves same for money it moves to right if
the words is long they don't stay in the same place, is this possible to modify? 
Thanks for every help dude appreciate it.
@user3366943

Comment: you can get to various properties of the table here
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table

i would really advice you to use a single table rather than two for your needs. and do not use div or span tags inside a <td> element. try to select cells within the table with css combinators like > + instead of placing them all over the html markup.

to show ellipsis when string is too long to fit

```
     white-space: nowrap; 
     overflow: hidden;
     text-overflow: ellipsis; 
```